# How to save anchor points in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6, photoshop-cs5

In Photoshop, I am drawing a irregular shaped polygon using pen tool by adding anchor points. I want to use this polygon with different style of lines (e.g., dashed line, dotted line, different color and thickness). Repeatedly drawing may be not accurate and time consuming. Is there a way to save this anchor points to future use or any other method is there to do this?

[image]

Comment: This is one of those "I wouldn't start from here" questions. If you're working in vector graphics, you ought to be using a vector-based app. Photoshop is a raster editor with some limited vector capability. Illustrator is a vector-based app with some limited raster capability. Horse for courses. Ps will save a vector in a layer, which you can then duplicate & treat differently, but it's not ideal for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've made your paths with the Pen tool, go into the Paths panel, and you should see a **Work Path**. If you drag that Work Path down to the **Create New Path** button, it will make a path called Path 1 that will be saved in your PSD file.

Refer to this screenshot:
[image: Drag the "Work Path" to the "Create New Path" button to save a path.]